# Getting error while updating all snaps using single command

Tags: 16.04, updates, snap

I am running Ubuntu-16.04 LTS. I have some snaps installed on my system. When I update these snaps one-by-one (by running `sudo snap refresh <snap name>`), I don't encounter any errors.

But when I update all the snaps using one single command, i.e. `sudo snap refresh all`, I get the following error :-

```
error: cannot refresh "all": cannot find snap "all"
```

But this offcial [Ubuntu Snaps' Guide](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy) states that `sudo snap refresh all` is the right method to update all snaps.

How do I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That documentation is incorrect. The command to refresh all your snaps is:

`sudo snap refresh`

NOTE: You do not need to manually run this. Your system will update all your snaps four times a day, using delta downloads to conserve bandwidth.